# PHP/html: Alternative to refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, html, wake-on-lan

I have a PHP script which are able to power on any computer in my network using WoL, check it's connectivity and then output a status. It's checking the connectivity by trying to connect to a port - say 3389/RDP, and when a connection is made, it outputs "SUCCESS", otherwise "FAILED". To get it to check the connectivity more than just a single time, it uses a meta tag that refreshes the page.

To make it look nice, I have a JS that loads and displays the output of the PHP script. But when it's checking connectivity of a machine, it refreshes the entire page, thus only showing the output of the php script and nothing else.

How do I make the PHP script retry the connection in some other way?

This is the php script:

```
<?php
##################################################
##     php WoL with port check - PRThomasUK.    ##
##             blog.pete-thomas.me.uk           ##
##################################################
//
// ################## user variables... ##################
// Friendly name for device, example "My Computer".
$device     = "roadrunner";
// IP address of device, example "x.x.x.x".
$deviceip   = "10.0.0.20";
// TCP Port on device to check, example "3389" = RDP, "80" = WebServer.
$deviceport = "3389";
// MAC address of NIC1 on device, example "00:00:00:00:00:00" or "00-00-00-00-00-00".
$devicemac1 = "00-11-22-33-44-55";
// MAC address of NIC2 on device, example "00:00:00:00:00:00" or "00-00-00-00-00-00". - Optional set to "" if NIC2 not required.
$devicemac2 = "";
// Number of times to attempt to connect to port on device after magic packet sent, example "10"
$maxtries   = "10";
// Broadcast address of network, example ""x.x.x.x". ("255.255.255.255" works in most cases.)
$broadcast  = "255.255.255.255";
// ICMP port number, default "7".
$udport     = "7";
// Timeout value for re-tries (in seconds), default "10".
$timeout    = "2";
// #######################################################
//
// ##### Read in variables from url #####
//
// $frame - used to determine which content to display when executed.
$frame      = "1";
// $tries - used to determine number of attempts at checking port beetween reloads, compared with maxtries.
$tries      = $_GET[ "tries" ];
// $pageurl - obtain URL used to access file, used when creating frameset & setting reloads.
$pageurl    = pageurl();
// Process variables used in frame2, increments tries & sets status to Success(1) or Failed(2)
if ( $frame == 1 ) {
                processurl();
}
// ###### Functions ######
//
// function pageurl( ) - Returns URL of page via PHP variables.
function pageurl( )
{
                $pageurl = "HTTP";
                if ( $_SERVER[ "HTTPS" ] == "on" ) {
                                $pageurl .= "S";
                }
                $pageurl .= "://";
                if ( $_SERVER[ "SERVER_PORT" ] != "80" ) {
                                $pageurl .= $_SERVER[ "SERVER_NAME" ] . ":" . $_SERVER[ "SERVER_PORT" ] . $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ];
                } else {
                                $pageurl .= $_SERVER[ "SERVER_NAME" ] . $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ];
                }
                $urlarts = explode( "?", $pageurl );
                $pageurl = $urlarts[ "0" ];
                return $pageurl;
}
//  function processurl( ) - Processes variables used in frame2, increments tries & sets status to Success(1) or Failed(2)
function processurl( )
{
                global $status, $tries, $maxtries;
                if ( $status == 0 && $tries < $maxtries - 1 ) {
                                $tries = $tries + 1;
                } else {
                                $status = 2;
                }
                if ( portcheck() == 0 ) {
                                $status = 1;
                }
}
//  function wakeonlan() - Attempts to send WoL packet and returns outcome.
function wakeonlan( $device, $mac )
{
                global $broadcast, $udport;
                $mac            = preg_replace( "/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", ":", $mac );
                $broadcast_byte = explode( ':', $mac );
                $hw_addr        = '';
                for ( $a = 0; $a < 6; $a++ )
                                $hw_addr .= chr( hexdec( $broadcast_byte[ $a ] ) );
                $msg = chr( 255 ) . chr( 255 ) . chr( 255 ) . chr( 255 ) . chr( 255 ) . chr( 255 );
                for ( $a = 1; $a <= 16; $a++ )
                                $msg .= $hw_addr;
                $s = socket_create( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP );
                if ( $s == false ) {
                                $content = "Error creating socket!\n";
                } else {
                                // setting a broadcast option to socket:
                                $opt_ret = socket_set_option( $s, 1, 6, true );
                                if ( $opt_ret < 0 ) {
                                                $content = "setsockopt() failed, error: " . strerror( $opt_ret ) . "\n";
                                }
                                if ( socket_sendto( $s, $msg, strlen( $msg ), 0, $broadcast, $udport ) ) {
                                                $content = "WoL packet sent to mac address " . $mac . "...\n";
                                                socket_close( $s );
                                } else {
                                                $content = "Failed to send WoL packet!";
                                }
                }
                return $content;
}
//  function portcheck( ) - Attempts to connect to TCP port on the device via a Socket, returns $errno.
function portcheck( )
{
                global $deviceip, $deviceport;
                $file = fsockopen( $deviceip, $deviceport, $errno, $errstr, 50 );
                if ( $errno == 0 ) {
                                fclose( $file );
                }
                return $errno;
}
// function htmlheader( ) - Returns HTML Header for TITLE and if Frame2 REFRESH set.
function htmlheader( )
{
                global $device, $frame, $tries, $maxtries, $status, $pageurl, $timeout;
                // global "custom" header settings
                $content = "<TITLE>PHP WoL ($device) - by PRThomasUK </TITLE>\n";
                //generate refresh header for frame2.
                if ( $status == 0 ) {
                                 $content .= "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"$timeout;url=$pageurl?&tries=$tries\">\n";
                }
                return $content;
}
// function htmlheader( ) - Returns HTML content for mainpage, frame1 & frame2 based on value of $frame.
function htmlcontent( )
{
                global $pageurl, $device, $deviceip, $deviceport, $devicemac1, $devicemac2, $frame, $tries, $maxtries, $status;
                if ( $frame == 1 ) {
                                if ( $status == 0 ) {
                                                $content = "<p>$tries/$maxtries retries failed.</p>\n";
                                } elseif ( $status == 1 ) {
                                                $content .= "<p>SUCCESS</p>\n";
                                } else {
                                                $content .= "<p>FAILED</p>\n"; }
                } else {
                                $content = "<FRAMESET rows=\"10,*\" frameborder=0 border=0>\n";
                                $content .= "<FRAME SRC=\"$pageurl?frame=2\">\n";
                                $content .= "<NOFRAMES>\n";
                                if ( $devicemac2 ) {
                                                $content .= "<BR>\n";
                                                $content .= wakeonlan( $device, $devicemac2 );
                                }
                                $content .= "<BR>\n";
                                $content .= "<BR>\n";
                                $content .= "<FONT COLOR=\"red\">\n";
                                $content .= "<H2>Your browser does not support frames...</H2>\n";
                                $content .= "</FONT>\n";
                                $content .= "<H3>Status of $device will not be monitored!</H3>\n";
                                $content .= "</NOFRAMES>\n";
                                $content .= "</FRAMESET>\n";
               } return $content; 
}
?>

<?php
echo htmlheader(); 
echo htmlcontent(); 
?>
```

And this is my index.php:

```
<html>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>WOL</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
$('#mydiv').load('status1.php', function() {alert('Loaded!');});
}
</script>

<?php
echo "10.0.0.20 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; roadrunner &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo '<a href="#" onclick="doSomething()">power on</a>';
?>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `iframe`.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>WOL</title>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="status1.php"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

BTW you should learn a bit about HTML syntax. Your code is crap.

Comment: But that wouldn't be triggered by a link or button, that would just run the php script on parent page load. And I tried using target="framename" with a href, but that won't work for some reason.

Comment: I switched to using iframe. But instead of using JS to set src of iframe, I just used 'target' in a href/button as that works cross-iframes and not just inside active page/frame. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Break off parts of the php page as sections or encaps in a function ( eg checkStatus($server="all"); )
Then when you want to load the page, by default if you dont provide a computer you load the page as normal, otherwise you can say just refresh this part.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer correct. The PHP still needs to update somehow, even if I put the connectivity check into its own "section"? And if I make a seperate JS for that, the output wouldn't be displayed in the same location on the website as the first JS (as far as i can figure)